# Handling more than one admin types login with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have an application requiring three User types(User, Agent, Admin) with login and requiring different devise modules.

```
                        User    AgentAdmin  AdminUser

confirmable              Yes        Yes         No
lockable                 Yes        Yes         No
timeoutable               No        Yes         Yes
Omniauthable             Yes        No          No
database_authenticatable Yes        Yes         Yes
recoverable              Yes        Yes         No
rememberable             Yes        Yes         No
trackable                Yes        Yes         Yes
validatable              Yes        Yes         Yes
```

Further these users may have additional columns based on their type. So, I want to create different tables based on their type.

Depending on my requirements, I decided to handle `AgentAdmin` and `AdminUser` with [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) with different namespaces(admin for `AdminUser` , agent for `AgentAdmin`). I have configured `authentication_method`, `current_user_method` and `logout_link_path` for both these namespaces as below.

```
config.load_paths = [File.join(Rails.root,'app','admin'), File.join(Rails.root,'app','agent')]

config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  admin.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
  admin.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
end

config.namespace :agent do |agent|
  agent.authentication_method = :authenticate_agent_admin!
  agent.current_user_method = :current_agent_admin
  agent.logout_link_path = :destroy_agent_admin_session_path
end
```

I have the following code in my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :agent_admins, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

This generates login paths only for `admin_users`.
If I set `config.default_namespace = :agent` in active_admin.rb config file, the login path for `agent_admin` is generated, but not `admin_users`.

All other ActiveAdmin paths are generated normally for both the namespaces.

How can I solve, to generate both the `login` paths handled by `activedmin`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
devise_for :agent_admins, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge({path: '/agent'})
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

This solved the issue.