# Rails activeadmin : how to make activeadmin have redirect path for each namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399030/handling-more-than-one-admin-types-login-with-activeadmin#_=_) and have tried it. Indeed, the resulting Routes are two different routes. In my case the code is like

```
devise_for: users, ActiveAdmin :: Devise.config.merge ({path:: user_belilah})
devise_for: admin_users, ActiveAdmin :: Devise.config
```

the code generates routes for `user_belilah` and `admin`

When I login through `user_belilah` route, the page is redirected to the `admin` path.

As I write

```
  config.default_namespace = :user_belilah
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.site_title = 'Admin Site'
    admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
    admin.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
    admin.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
    user.root_to = 'dashboard#index'
  end

  config.namespace :user_belilah do |user|
    user.site_title = 'User Site'
    user.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
    user.current_user_method = :current_user
    user.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
    user.root_to = 'products#index'
  end
```

I've written default_namespace for `user_belilah` and create `.root_to` for each namespace. Then when i login, I successfully redirected to `user_belilah / dashboard`. When I login through route admin,again, the page is redirected to  `user_belilah`

how to make activeadmin have two redirect paths? 
it seems only  **one of them** is a redirect route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find the answer , i just write code to override method  `after_sign_in_path_for` in `application_controller.rb`  like this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.class == AdminUser
      admin_dashboard_path
    elsif resource.class  == User
      root_path
    end
  end
```

therefore activeadmin has two kind of redirect path when we sign in