# Active Admin namespace configuration conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am working with my clients existing active admin installation and trying to add an additional user group using namespaces. I have followed this post:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399030/handling-more-than-one-admin-types-login-with-activeadmin#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399030/handling-more-than-one-admin-types-login-with-activeadmin#_=_)

I am unfortunately getting some strange behaviors. If I go to admin I can login with one of the original admin accounts as expected, but my logout button and my email are missing from the status bar. If I force a logout and go to /users then I can go straight to its dashboard even though I just logged out. If I log out of their or go to /user/login then I can log back into the user dashboard, but only with my admin accounts, it will not use the users table and the strangest thing is that it in that dashboard my user name and log out button are back, but it shows the last user from the users database that logged in instead of the admin user that just logged in (I had the user view working previously and it seems to be remembering that user). Finally, it looks like my current_user object is nil as i am getting "undefined method `superadmin?' for nil:NilClass" when I test a custom attribute I created.

It seems like these config variable are not being uniformly set by the different name spaces and they are working somewhat on top of each other. Any help would be much appreciated....

Here is my active_admin.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  #config.current_user_method = :current_user

 # config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path

  config.batch_actions = true

  config.load_paths = [File.expand_path('app/admin', Rails.root), File.expand_path('app/users', Rails.root),]

  #config.default_namespace = :admin

  config.namespace :admin do |admin|

  admin.site_title = "Checkin Admin"

  admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

  admin.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path

  admin.current_user_method = :current_user

  end

  config.namespace :users do |users|
   # c.authentication_method = :logged_in?
    users.site_title = "Checkins"
    users.current_user_method = :current_user
   users.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
CheckinAdmin::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge({path: '/users'})
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

Here the schema of my user, it is identical to an admin_user:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Please let me know any other information that I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that the `users` namespace conflict with the User model, see: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4402